# SQL Server migrate new data into old schema

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have converted MS Access tables and queries to SQL Server tables and views and linked them back to Access. While I was doing this migration, people were using the old Access frontend not linked to SQL Server. Now, the data that I have in SQL Server is the old data when I started the migration. I have created tables, indexes, queries etc in my SQL Server which uses the old data.

Now, I want to deploy the SQL database and link it to Access. Is there a way for me to delete my old data and migrate the new data to SQL Server database while preserving all the schema?

Edit 1:

[image: Added]

Comment: Run a bunch of DELETE and INSERT SELECT actions. You better shut down user interaction while this is accomplished.

Comment: Running DELETE and inserts on a typical small application of 50-60 highly related tables and keeping the PK/FK pairs intact etc. intact is quite a challenge. You have to be careful to up-load the parent tables first. So for tables related 2-3 levels deep, then a simple delete and insert  falls VERY short of a migration. I often spend a WHOLE DAY just changing and making settings on the migration assistant. The migration assistant saves many days, and will turn a typical migration project from say 4-5 days of work down to a half day, but it still requires significant amounts of settings.

Comment: Just choosing what data types you want access to translate from can take some time. (for example, do you choose bit fields, or int columns for your true false collums from access. Same goes for dealing with date ranges (out of range). And also that of setting the project to NOT use say datetime2 column. I could type on for another 100+ pages, but migration projects will involve days of work, and simply delete + inserts are not even in the same ballpark for what is typically required for a access to sql migration project.

Comment: To re-migration you simply re-name the back end yuo used for migration, and now copy the production access back end to the SAME location (same file). At this point, you can re-run your migration project on that database. As noted, you likely spent a day (or two) setting up that migration project. you can SWAP OUT the access back end to the new one, and your project WILL STILL run.  So this is how  you use the exact same SSMA migration project As noted, you really don't want to make a whole new project each time, as that is considerable amounts of work.

Comment: It is assumed that you migrated the data, and then worked on a NEW front end linked + connected to SQL server. When you have that working all nice. Then to deploy for production, you will take the access back end they been working on all this time (while you building the new system for sql server). You migrated that updated back end using the SAME migration project (SSMA), you then now deploy your sql based working front end to each work station.  So you will distribute the new front end (a compiled accDE) with the tables already linked to sql server.

Comment: This is what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did the migration using SSMA (Sql migration assistant for Access) then you can simply re-run that saved project.

The first time you run SSMA, it will create the data tables on sql server, and then transfer the data.

However, you can open that same SSMA project again, and re-run it, will give you the option to delete the data on SQL server, and send up the existing Access data again.

One of the “really” great features of SSMA is it lets you re-send the data. So you can slice and dice, and try the migration MANY MANY times.

Once you get the migration going the way you want, you migrate the data. You then work on getting your front end to work with sql server. During this time, no doubt users are still using the older system (non sql server).

For example, SSMA allows you to add a PK to each table (if it does not have one). I often found a “few” tables such as for driving combo boxes etc. does not (did not) have a PK for that table that say drives a combo box. So during the migration, you want to let SSMA create the PK for you. You can do this manually after the migration, but then you need to write down some “cheat” notes, since as you point out, you going to have to do the migration again later on.

So, if you make any “manual” changes to the data structures, then you want to “save” those changes in the event that you migrate again. The beauty of this, is WHEN you in the table design mode (sql server), you can right click, and choose “script” changes. So if you make say 10 or more changes to each table, you can save your changes into a sql script. So now you can migrate, and then run those scripts.

Now, after the migration, you get to work making this front end work with SQL server. During this time no doubt users are STILL working on the old system (access back end).

Once your new front end is working fine with sql server, then you pick a day for the new roll out. You after work, or during down time, re-run the SSMA project you saved. The result is now SQL server has the most up to date data. And then you are now able to roll out and deploy out the new front end that is linked to SQL server.

As noted, while SSMA can migrate Access queries, I VERY strong recommend you don’t do this. Just migrate the data, and link the front end tables to sql server. At this point, 99% of your Access appcation will work as before. You “may” have to change the VBA open recordset commands (to add dbOpenDynaset, and dbSeeChageesto that openRecordSet command (but that is a global search and replace – not much time at all).

So you likely have lots of code like this:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

And you need to change above to:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

The above will thus allow 99% of your VBA reocrdset code to work as before without changes.

The only “common” got ya, is with a Access back end, the autonumber ID is generated INSTANT as a you dirty a form, or dirtry (add too) a record. This allows code to grab the auto number PK right away.

So such old code as:

```
Set rstRecords = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblmain")
rstRecords.AddNew
' lots of some "code" here follows

 lngPK = rst!ID
```

In above, note how my VBA code grabs the PK auto number.

In sql server,  you cannot grab that PK until AFTER you force the record save. And DAO has a VERY nasty issue is that after you issue a update (during add only – I repeat during adding reocrds only!!!), then the record pointer jumps off the current record. This DOES NOT occur when you using DAO recordsets to update a existing record (again: only for new reocdors).

So, so above code now becomes:

```
Set rstRecords = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblmain")
rstRecords.AddNew

' code can go here to add data, or set values to the reocord

rstRecords.Update
rstRecords.Bookmark = rstRecords.LastModified
lngNext = rstRecords!ID
rstRecords.Close
```

So, for code that grabs the autonumber PK right away, we have to do two things:
Force a record write (update)
And then after the update, re-positon the record pointer. (you ONLY need this re-postion when adding – not edits, but I often do this anyway). This re-position issue is perhaps my LARGEST pain of using DAO (ADO does not require this re-position).

So your code add/sets the fields etc. in that reocrdset do NOT have to be changes. So leave that code that does whatever the heck the code did before.

Now issue the update, AND THEN GRAB the autonumber PK.

So above should cover 99% of your VBA code you have to change. Even in a rather large project, the above issue will only occur in a few places. (I find that I can search for “.add” in the code base, and rather fast determine if code is grabbing the autonumber PK before the “.update” command is issued.

The same goes for forms. When a user starts typing, the form becomes “dirty”. With Access back end, the autonumber PK can be grabbed by code, but with sql server back end, you have to issue a record save in the form, and THEN grab the PK ID.

So, you add this one line:

```
If me.Dirty = True then me.Dirty = false

lngID = me!id
```

So you added the one line to force a record save (me.Dirty = false).

And again I tend to find even with say 150 forms, only 1 or 2 will do this “grabbing” of PK id before the forms record has been saved. So this “lack” of autonumber being able to grabbed for new records will occur for both forms, and VBA reocordset code. Few forms do grab the PK autonumber ID, but some do need this (say to add child records). However, existing forms + sub forms do NOT have this issue, since access ALWAYS issues a record save when the focus jumps from the main for to any sub form.

Anyway, once you get the new front end working (and of course one linked the front end using the same table names as before).

If I recall, SSMA tends to put “dbo” in front of the Access table link names – you don’t want that. The dbo schema on sql server side is the default, and again that should not pose any issues or problems.

So yes, SSMA allows you to re-run the migration, and it allows you to delete your data on SQL server during that re-migration. You not need to delete the old data, SSMA can do this for you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been playing around with this for past 3 hours and I realized that instead of using the previous saved project you can also simply start a new project, link to the SQL server database and if you hit skip all on overwrite schema, and choose to migrate data only. This will preserve all your schema in SQL server and simply migrate the data only.

Comment: I started learning Access and SQL Server about 2-3 months ago and had a lot of confusions along the way. I have a second stack overflow account as well. You have been a tremendous help last 3 months as you have answered a lot of my questions. Your answers are always detailed and easy to understand. I have read your blogs, and read a lot of your replies in other forums as well. I always wanted to thank you but there is no messaging feature on StackOverflow. Thank you!

Comment: I would REALLY work on re-using the SAME migration project. Evyone has to migrate multiple times. So you spend a day  (or two) setting up the migration project. There will be at least 20+ or even MORE settings you had to make in that migration project (and if not then your migration likely not done right). If you create a new migration, then your 20+ settings will lost and you have to re-do them. So simple things like settings to use datetime (not datetime2) needs to be changed in the project. Perhaps your memory is super and you don't' forget all the settings you had to make for the migration